# how to retrieve data without using outer joins, or without using any joins?

Tags: php, mysql, join

How can we retrieving data from multiple tables without using "LEFT JOIN" or "RIGHT JOIN" in mysql?
OR 
Is it Possible by using PHP/Mysql?

some of the case i can retrive data. such as when we use "two tables" or there have no complex "WHERE" condition.

But when i use 5,6,7----15 tables that case it is impossible for me to retrive data.

Please can any one help me.
Thanks Advance.

Comment: Is your question how to retrieve data without using outer joins, or without using *any* joins?

Comment: please let us know why you have such requirement. As per my understanding, it's always good to use join while fetching data from multiple table. You can use EXISTS clause at place of joins.

Comment: hi eggyal
yea i need such thinks questions ans.
how to retrieve data without using outer joins, or without using any joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "alias" instead of "Join".

Assume you have 4 table.

Syntax:

```
Select * from Table1 A, Table2 B, Table3 C, Table4 D
where A.id= B.id and A.city=C.city and B.subject=D.subject
```

Comment: You're using cross-joins (the `,` operator).

Answer (score 1):

- Do a search on the first table,
- On the second table do a `SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.fk_table_1 IN ($pks_from_table_one)`

and go on ... but this means you will do `n` queries, with `n` round trips to the DB - I've heard that some companies forbids `JOIN`s and sometimes it is indeed better - but I didn't do it yet and don't recommend it either.

Comment: hi 'Tudor Constantin'
thanks for ur reply.
ur explanation is right. personaly i also don't recommand it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have foods and people. You want to get the foods people like.

foods: id,food_name

people: id,name,food_id

food_id here refers to the id field in the foods table.

Simply do:
SELECT people.name,food.food_name FROM people,foods WHERE people.food_id=foods.id

Comment: Thanks 'fmarton' for your reply.

but My boss have told me to execute only individual 'select' query for every table and using php array merging function without any kind of joining query.

Comment: It's really hard to judge the reasons without the background, but querying mysql will be much faster and more effective than in php.
What about embedded selects? Its still in mysql and you can clearly see the results, every column is one select. However is only applicaple if the desired structure makes it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by adding a subquery without using any JOIN statement, in the example I gave you three tables were used **to extract Users that are our customers and their mount is less or equal than 999**, check it out..

```
Select TUsers.names TCustomers.names 
FROM TUsers, TCustomers
Where TUsers.id = TCustomer.id AND TCustomers.id IN
(Select TCustomer.id
FROM TCustomer
WHERE TCustomer.amount >= 999)
```

Rate if it helps :)

Comment: You're using a cross-join (the `,` operator).